# Modal matrix rows

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

A typical numerical matrix diagonalization routine (such as `eigh()` in `numpy`) returns a list of matrix eigenvalues and corresponding normalized eigenvectors in the form of a unitary "modal matrix" $U$ (whose columns they are) which diagonalizes the original matrix. Is there a simple interpretation of modal matrix rows? These rows can be thought of as columns of $U^T$, but $U^T$ is also a unitary matrix diagonalizing the original matrix. Are the rows of $U$ also transposed eigenvectors of the original matrix? If so, then what is then the eigenvalue corresponding to $n$th column?

Comment: What you are doing when diagonalising is just a change of bases, a [similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) (while changing orthonormal bases it is a special case of that, unitary transformations). A diagonalisable $n\times n$ matrix will have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. If you consider this set of eigenvectors as the basis, the matrix will be diagonalised in that basis.